# openrefine flag changed rows

Tags: data-cleaning, openrefine, opendata

I'm using openrefine to cleanup an excel data set.  I have about 70 operations and I've been cutting and pasting on different data sets.  I maintain a record id and export to a new excel sheet.  Then I reload the sheet using the record id.

It works well, but I have to reload the entire database even if only a handful of records change.  is there an easy way to flag changed records so I only export / import the changed records to the application?

Can I easily add a flag to the 70 operations to tag only changed records?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't currently a straightforward way to do this in OpenRefine, but it would make an interesting [feature request](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues).  The best way to do this currently would probably be to work with CSV or TSV files and diff the before & after files to come up with a delta to load.